# PI controller response frequency

Tags: frequency, control-system, pid-controller, frequency-response

I'm writing a report on the PI controller I built for my university project, which is supposed to keep a magnetic ball levitating underneath a controllable electromagnet. The prototype works with a table tennis ball, but the full scale project is supposedly for a levitating light ball, which would be outside, thus in the rainy and windy conditions of Belgium. I've decided to consider that rain doesn't really affect the stability of the ball, given that one raindrop's worth of force (i.e. the effect of one single raindrop hitting the ball at a time) is very very weak, even during cloudbursts. In order to be able to assume only one drop is gonna be affecting the ball at the same time, I also have to assume the controller will be able to correct about 1000 impacts per second, which is the average amount I'll be receiving during such episodes of very intensive rain.

I was wondering if a PI controller can actually react this quickly (about 1000 corrections/s).

Thank you.

Comment: depends on what you are implementing the PI controller in?  analogue... easily... a microcontroller with a clock frequency of 100Hz ... no

Comment: Each individual raindrop may be considered as an impulse, but the transient effect of each raindrop lasts much longer than 1 ms. So the combined effect is more like a step.

Comment: It's an analog controller.

Comment: Does considering them as steps change a lot?

Comment: sort of, while the frequency of said event maybe low, how your controller responds to the "step" could be affected. A properly tuned loop would be able to disregard such a component.

Comment: Consider this. Your supposition is 1000/s impacts, but how long does the effect of one impact last? is there any wobble? how much? how long until it dampens out.  rather than worry about the 1000/s worry about what one could do BECAUSE if there is a nice resonance you only need a couple in a row to cause your controller to go unstable

Comment: So if I assume I've done a decent job at tuning the loop, I can really just say that any disturbance would get corrected without really interfering with the stability of the system? Also, getting resonance with raindrops sounds quite unlikely to happen...

Comment: Why would you consider each single raindrop? Treat the input as a continuous signal. You need the differential equation model of the system, then transform this to Laplace.

Comment: exactly. My point is, the 1000/s is the wrong piece of information to be concentrating on. You have a disturbance coming into the system that you need to counter

Comment: "resonance with raindrops sounds quite unlikely to happen"   Resonance from humans was considered quite unlikely until marching soldiers ripped a bridge to bits... if you have not quantified your system & its expected disturbances, how can you make such a statement. Already raindrops are capable of upsetting your magnetic levitation THUS something is needed and that something can be unstable...

Comment: Okay so let me just recap. I'm gonna calculate the effect from one single raindrop, see if that can possibly damage the system in any way, apply some safety coefficients for resonance and that kind of stuff, then decide whether the effect really is negligible. Does that sound right?

Comment: No. An impulse train with an impulse separation period much less than the time constant of the ball-in-a-fluid looks like a constant force.

Comment: Can I model that without using Laplace transforms (which I haven't learned yet, first year undergrad here).

Comment: Yes, have you covered linear differential equations in class?

Comment: I have, yes. Not very in-depth though.

Comment: Why are you using a PI controller, because you've been told to, or because that's what you've chosen? A PID has more degrees of freedom, and will be easier to get stable, especially with a mechanical system where force integrates to velocity integrates to position.

Comment: We were supposed to use a comparator implemented with a PWM transistor, but that didn't feel challenging enough. Using a PID means having derivative control, so I'd have to be wary of too high frequencies, which is kinda bound to happen here.

Comment: get the basics working 1st... THEN if you have time add a PI(D) if you go in like this over the minimum you risk outright failure. either scheme needs a comparator+tran to make pwm so start with that

Comment: I got their scheme working already, but I wanted to work with a voltage to current converter instead of the transistor. Is that equally as good or not?

Comment: The ball looks like a mass suspended by a lightly damped spring. The control system aims to apply forces to the mass to keep it stationary in the face of external forces applied to it. This is quite a complex system for 1st year undergrad without knowledge of Laplace. What exactly are you expected to achieve? Do you have a hardware system that just needs tuning?

Comment: They gave us a simple circuit schematic that we had to build, and test. Then we were supposed to change little things in order to make it better. I do have some knowledge of Laplace but self-taught, so if they start asking questions about it I'd quickly look pretty stupid. Their philosophy is asking us to do stuff we can't actually understand, which forces us to try and supposedly helps us to understand those concepts more easily once we're taught the theory behind them.

Comment: Ok. Now it's clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to model the rain as a unidirectional disturbance with "popcorn noise" characteristics. Since you have no D (derivative) control characteristic the controller responds only to the error and the integral of error.

Depending on the system characteristics you will likely see the error increase during a sudden downpour, followed by a correction to zero error as the integral term takes effect. There will be some (likely small) perturbations on the error as individual raindrops impact. You can estimate the maximum from a single drop from basic physics, assuming the controller does nothing to correct immediately. If the downpour stops suddenly, the ball would be expected to overshoot a bit upwards, then come back down to zero average error.

The controller bandwidth will typically be a lot higher than the closed loop system bandwidth. The proportional term on an analog controller can easily respond far faster than macroscopic normal mechanical systems (hundreds of kHz or MHz). The closed loop system is limited in practice by how much control authority you have. The math will tell you that you can make a battleship turn on a dime with the right controller, but there is not enough power in the engines to make that happen in reality.